# Test 5: Communication with stackauth.com – failed

Tags: support, login, chat, authentication

i use Chrome and notscripts, recently get a failure to authorize with stackexchange and cannot chat with a moderator anymore.

http://chat.stackexchange.com/help

Is this a problem with the recent update to Chrome?

Clearing or resetting HTML5 as suggested does not help, how to do this manually?

Fails in Incognito mode also.

How do I sort this out, thanks.

Chrome version 13.0.782.107 m

[image]

[image]

.

If I disable Notscripts, still not working.

Clean re-installed Chrome Error persists, Looked in my local storage folder and this file was in there "http_chat.stackexchange.com_0.localstorage"

[image]

POSSIBLE CAUSE:
Appears that setting "Ignore exceptions and block third-party cookies from being set" in chrome options causes this error, I have had it set this way for a long time, but now it causes problems, strange, uncheck the box and all is fine, toggle it back and error returns.

Can some one else verify this?

.

Comment: I just tried logging into chat.stackexchange.com, and I had no problems using the latest version of Chrome. What happens in Incognito mode (which should disable all extensions by default)? Have you tried a fresh install of Chrome? My guess is NotScripts is causing the problem.

Comment: Try reinstalling Chrome fresh, with no extensions. I have the exact same build of Chrome and no problems.

Comment: ah, I see now. After enabling that option, the test fails in the same place for me as well. Any more information would have to come from the dev team. I suspect it may have to do with the storage request being for stackauth.com on a page served by stackexchange.com, but I'm not quite certain.

Comment: Great, I am not insane ;-> thanks. I also got some errors trying to log into the HP forums, different behavior though, but both cured now, I suspect it is a chrome bug, never did it on earlier versions as I have always had this checked on previous versions of chrome.

Comment: From doing some googling, it looks like that option will completely deny any third party cookies. While not stated upfront, that may also completely deny third party HTML5 LocalStorage, which could be causing this problem. Let's wait to see what a dev says.

Comment: In the meantime Moab, you can use the alternate escape hatch to get into chat: http://superuser.com/users/chat-stackexchange-login

Comment: For now I have disabled that feature, so I can chat for now, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "block third-party cookies from being set" thing sounds plausible; some paranoia plugins may consider the localStorage used in a cross-domain IFRAME a third-party cookie.

The [Stack Exchange global network login](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/) (also used for the chat.SE login) [requires this to work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work/64274#64274).